# iOS App it's not updated as it should

Tags: ios, updates

The app I'm developing has one screen with several icons, and those icons are shown accordingly to the information found in an plist that it's stored in an resources directory. I updated the plist in order to show a new icon and submitted a new version of the app. When the app gets updated on my device, it doesn't shows the new icon, but if I delete the app from the device and install it again from the app store, the new icon appears. What can be the source of this problem?

Thank you for the help,

Comment: Have you tried to clean and build your before running it on your device? Sometimes project resource are not updated when you just run the app.

Comment: When I run the app, build it, submit to the store and have a fresh install on a device, everything goes fine. The problem it's when you already have an earlier version of the app installed on your device, then you update to the new version, and this particular update doesn't happen. It seems the plist icon configuration file doesn't get updated.

Comment: Are you copying the file or just reading it from the app main bundle?

Comment: I'm reading the file from the app main bundle.